# Define Postgresql Column as Serial in go-pg ORM

Tags: postgresql, go, orm, go-pg

I want to create different tables in a postgresql db. For now I am using the go-pg ORM package. I already found a possible way to this using the following code:

```
func set_up_tables(db *pg.DB) error {
    models := []interface{}{
        (*User)(nil),
        (*Account)(nil),
        (*Transaction)(nil),
    }

    for _, model := range models {
        err := db.Model(model).CreateTable(&orm.CreateTableOptions{
            IfNotExists: true,
        })
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

For now lets just look at the user struct which I defined like this:

```
type User struct {
    UserId    string `json:"userId"`
    Email     string `json:"emailAddress"`
    Firstname string `json:"firstName"`
    Lastname  string `json:"lastName"`
    Address   string `json:"address"`
}
```

I want the userId Column to be a Serial, which means being unique, not null, and autoincremented.
Is there a way to do this using the ORM, or Go code? I have already been able to change it in pgadmin by hand but there are more structs with Ids that should be changed and I do not want to do it by hand ofc.
And as additional question is this a good way to implement it?

Comment: [Don't use serial](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial)

Answer (score 1):

If you [review the documentation](https://pg.uptrace.dev/models/#struct-tags) you'll find that you need to be using `pg` struct tags for your model, not `json` tags; and that PG is an ORM, but *not* a migration tool. You don't use PG to define your schema, only to map your schema to your data structures.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am not sure if I understand your answer correctly. What would I use to define my schemas, is there a package or SQL or something else? And for the `pg` tags yes I saw them but how would one structure that would I define define two different structs for the concept of a User? One with json tag for api communication and one for db communication?

Comment: I found a package [golang migrate](https://github.com/golang-migrate) to migrate and start a db with golang(more or less).